# Data not added into firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got the Firebase Android Tutorial from [here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-android-tutorial-writing-firebase-data/) and followed every single step in this tutorial. However, when I click create `button` and refresh the `firebase`, the database data I get is always empty.

Can someone help me in figuring out what's the problem?

This is my `firebase`

[image]

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {
    public static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://healthy-app-30d65.firebaseio.com/";   
}
```

**Register**

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editTextName;
    EditText editTextAddress;
    TextView textViewPersons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Button buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
        textViewPersons = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPersons);

        //Click Listener for button
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creating firebase object
                Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

                //Getting values to store
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
                String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating Person object
                Person person = new Person();

                //Adding values
                person.setName(name);
                person.setAddress(address);

                //Storing values to firebase
                ref.child("Person").setValue(person);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like my Firebase code at all, but have you logged in or changed the authentication so you don't need to ?

Comment: The tutorial is for the legacy Firebase.  Consider starting over with the new Firebase SDK, [Setup guide here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you follow the latest firebase samples. You can find step-by-step setup and sample project at [Google Firebase Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0)

For example, storing values to real time database is updated

from  `ref.child("Person").setValue(person);` to `ref.child("Person").push().setValue(person);`

Answer (score 3):

You're using a tutorial that was written for the legacy Firebase console (firebase.com) and SDK version (2.x). But your Firebase project was created on the new Firebase console (firebase.google.com).

While most of the API will continue to work, there are a few differences that are hitting you here:

1. projects created on the new console are configured to only allow authenticated users to read/write. The simplest way to (temporarily) work around this problem is to read the [first note in blue on this documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data). That explains how to make your database world readable/writeable again.
2. the authentication from the Firebase 2.x SDK will not work against projects created on the new Firebase console.

So #1 may be a good quick workaround, but you really should take an updated tutorial, such as the ones suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The new Firebase is not compatible with legacy code (https://wwww.firebase.com), you'll have to setup your Android project to the latest [SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). You may refer to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#install_the_new_firebase_sdk_numbered) on how to migrate your database code.